# Apple Watch interface strangely cropped/shifted

Tags: xcode, watchkit, apple-watch

I'm creating a workout tracking app and in order to switch between view controller I use `WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers(withNames:contexts:)` to load a single controller that in `awake(withContext:)` hides/shows some elements and changes the text in some some labels. No problem here but sometimes the view is not loaded correctly and appears to be shifted a little bit to left and stretched vertically cropping some of the text: as you can see in the screenshots below the left part of the *A* and *5* is missing as well as the bottom of *NEXT: ...* and the green button is not centered:

[image]
[image]

I've tried delaying the updates to the view by invoking the code via `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` but that does nothing unfortunately and the only way to fix the problem is to terminate and relaunch the app but as this is not possible from the watch I have to uninstall it and reinstall it again, even reloading again the root controller does not help (the second screenshot is after said reload). Someone has an idea why this is happening?

[Project on GitHub](https://github.com/piscoTech/GymTracker), the controller with this problem is `ExecuteWorkoutInterfaceController` in `ExecuteWorkoutIC.swift`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your storyboard layout and also maybe not use WKInterfaceController.reloadRootControllers and just have a method that hides and shows elements.

Comment: Reloading the root controller works fine and is needed as I need to change the hierarchy of the interface controllers, I should add that the problem appears only when reloading the root controller after the app is relaunched after a crash